# Failing to see the result for $\frac{dB_t}{B_t}$ for $B_t = 100e^{-r(T-t)}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Given a function:

$$B_t = 100e^{-r(T-t)}$$

We can perform a taylor series expansion for $r$ keeping $T, t$ fixed:

$$\displaystyle{B_t \approx (100e^{-r_{0} (T-t)})(1-(T-t)(r-r_0) + \frac{1}{2}(T-t)^2(r-r_0)^2)}$$

The author then says that the above can be divided by the first multiplier, i.e. by $(100e^{-r_0 (T-t)})$ to obtain:

$$\frac{dB_t}{B_t} = -(T-t)(r-r_0) + \frac{1}{2}(T-t)^2(r-r_0)$$

I cannot see how they get to this last line by simply dividing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the author is doing the following - 
$$B_t(r) = B_t(r_0) + B_t(r_0)(-(T-t)(r-r_0) + \frac{1}{2}(T-t)^2(r-r_0)^2)$$

Now, if $|r-r_0|<<1$, then $B_t(r) - B_t(r_0) \approx dB_t(r_0)$.

So, $$dB_t(r_0) =B_t(r_0)(-(T-t)(r-r_0) + \frac{1}{2}(T-t)^2(r-r_0)^2) $$

and the result follows.

Comment: wouldn't we call $dB_t(r) \approx B_t(r)-B_t(r_0)$ since we are talking about $r \rightarrow r_0$? Thanks for this explanation. Now it is clear

Comment: No, as the derivative is defined as - $$dB_t(r_0) = lim_{r\to r_0} \frac {B_t(r)-B_t(r_0)}{r-r_0}$$ So, we see that the dervative at $r_0$ is found bby taking $r\to r_0$.